# javaFX - Display reCaptcha

Tags: java, javafx, web-scraping, webview, google-search

Im trying to send a query to google (explicitly without API). the problem is, that google recognizes suspicios data transfer and sows me the "Im not a robot" captcha (reCaptcha).
I want to show it to the User and he/she can complete it to go on. 
Im using javaFX webView with webEngine. I can show it to the user, but allthough I solve the captcha correctly, it says mit that I awnsered it wrong...
So here is my code:

```js
        URI uri = URI.create(url);
        Map<String, List<String>> headers = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
        headers.put("Set-Cookie", Arrays.asList("APISID=E2mcDXOq7ze9A2Vg/Ar9qIklbtuxLfJA1Z", "CONSENT=YES+DE.de+20160612-12-0", "HSID=AZqBaYgd1dLE0PVXI"));
        try {
            java.net.CookieHandler.getDefault().put(uri, headers);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        WebEngine webEngine = wvCaptchaView.getEngine();
        webEngine.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.37");
        webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        com.sun.javafx.webkit.WebConsoleListener.setDefaultListener(
                (webView, message, lineNumber, sourceId) ->
                        System.out.println("Console: [" + sourceId + ":" + lineNumber + "] " + message)
        );
        webEngine.load(url);
```

Im also thinking, that it renders kind of wrong, because on clicking a tile in the captcha, I think sometimes it shows the tick on a wrong place. Is there something, that Im missing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: in similar situation